# How to do Outer Join on >2 Tables (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, outer-join, multiple-tables

I'm not sure how to describe my table structure, so hope this makes sense...

I have 3 tables in hierarchical relationship such that A has a one to many relationship to B which in turn has a one to many relationship with C.  The trick is that the foreign key in B and C are allowed to be null (i.e. no parent defined).  I also have D and E with no relation to A, B or C (directly).

Finally, I have F which is a join table with many to one relationships with C, D and E.  None of its fields (FKs to the other tables) are nullable.

I would like to write a SQL statement that joins all the tables in a single result set.  I know I have to user outer joins because I want all of A returned regardless of whether or not it has children in B and similar with B and C.

**Question One:** I have been looking at the ANSI outer join syntax (I've only used Oracle "(+)" before) and cannot find an example that outer joins more than 2 tables.  Can someone provide/point to an example?

**Question Two:** Is it possible to include records from tables D and E based on the join table F?  If so, is this done with outer joins?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Of course, right after I post this, I found an example that answers question 1.  However, question 2 still has me stumped.

Example:

```
         SELECT A.a,
                B.b,
                C.c
           FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON B.a = A.a
FULL OUTER JOIN C ON C.b = B.b
```

Comment: You probably don't want FULL OUTER JOIN; it exists, but it is very seldom used (or useful).

Comment: You have not specified which columns in F join with each of the other tables - which means that noone can give a definitive answer.

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the recordset you'd like to get? A's, B's an C's are not very informative names.

Comment: @Jonathan, as I understand the ANSI joins (and I admit I'm just learning) I need to use a full join because I want all records from table A, even if there's no child records in table B AND all records from Table B, even if there's no foreign key to table A defined.  A left or right join would only give me nulls for one direction of the relationship.  Table F only has 3 fields which are foreign keys to tables C, D and E.  Bill did a great job in his answer "drawing" the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarification, the uppercase letters referred to tables and the lowercase to the primary/foreign key columns.  I probably should have written it similar to Quassnoi, but will keep with this since that's how it started.

This SQL returns the results I'm loooking for:

```
         SELECT A.a,
                B.b,
                C.c,
                D.d,
                E.e
           FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON B.a = A.a
FULL OUTER JOIN C ON C.b = B.b
FULL OUTER JOIN F ON F.c = C.c
FULL OUTER JOIN D ON D.d = F.d
FULL OUTER JOIN E ON E.e = F.e
```

I tried to set up my SQL like Bill's but using FULL joins instead of LEFT ones, but it didn't return the same results as mine.  I can't say that I fully understand his SQL, but the INNER joins filtered some of the results.

Answer (score 10):

So I visualize your schema like this:

```
A --o< B --o< C --< F >-- D
                      >-- E
```

You can certainly do multiple joins, and you can also group join expressions with parentheses just like you can group arithmetic expressions.

```
SELECT ...
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  B LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    C LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      F INNER JOIN D ON D.d = F.d
        INNER JOIN E ON E.e = F.e
      ) ON C.c = F.c
    ) ON B.b = C.b
) ON A.a = B.a
```

These parentheses are *not* subqueries, they're just grouping join operations.

Comment: That's a great way to "draw" my schema. Thanks!  I need to spend some time figuring out if your select statement does what I'm hoping, but I do think I need to use FULL joins as per my comment above to Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select a.*, b.*, c.*
 from a
 left outer join b on a.b_id = b.id
 left outer join c on a.c_id = c.id
```

Now, getting D, E & F in there gets trickier:

```
select c.*, d.*, e.*
from C
inner join f on c.id = f.c_id
inner join d on d.id = f.d_id
inner join e on d.id = f.e_id
```

Then we put it all together:

```
 select a.*, b.*, cde.*
 from a
 left outer join b on a.b_id = b.id
 left outer join 
 (select c.id as c_id, c.*, d.*, e.*
   from C
   inner join f on c.id = f.c_id
   inner join d on d.id = f.d_id
   inner join e on d.id = f.e_id) CDE
 on a.c_id = cde.c_id
```

Comment: Thanks!  We must have been posting at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.*
FROM    a
LEFT JOIN
        b
ON      b.a = a.id
LEFT JOIN
        с
ON      c.b = b.id
LEFT JOIN
        f
ON      f.с = c.id
LEFT JOIN
        d
ON      d.id = f.d
LEFT JOIN
        e
ON      e.id = f.e
```