# Full outer join between 2 tables using an additional table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with a select.
I try to get a join between 2 tables: `Items` and `Characters`.
The thing is, I have a third table `Items_history`.
I want my select to show ALL items and ALL characters and, if there's a record, that a character had or has an item, show it.

Shortly speaking, I want something like this:

```
ID | Character
 4 | 
 5 |
10 | Player1
12 | Player1
12 | Player2
13 | Player3
20 | Player2
   | Player4
   | Player5
```

My code right now:

```
SELECT Items.ID, Character.Name
FROM Items_history
RIGHT JOIN Items
ON Items.ID = Items_history.ID
RIGHT JOIN Characters
ON Characters.Name = Items_history.Name;
```

Comment: You wrote "Full outer join" in the question title, but use `RIGHT JOIN` in your query. Simply changing the joins to `FULL JOIN` should return the expected result.

Comment: You might find this helpful as it shows how to nest the joins: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3721771/2515265

Comment: As @dnoeth suggested, simple replacing right joins with full joins gives [expected results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d198a/1).